# Autogenerate numbers based on "Group" in GroupByExpression RadGrid and display it in RadGrid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a trouble in implementing below requirement.

**Current RadGrid:** Below is the `RadGrid` in which I am using `GroupByExpressions` 
to display/show data grouped with "Business Unit" column.

In `RadGrid` column 2nd(*InvoiceLineNo*) and 3rd(*InvoiceNo*), I am auto generating the numbers using Stored Procedure.
**i.e.,** for "InvoiceLineNo" column, Autogenerated No's are: 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08.......n 
for "InvoiceNo" column, Autogenerated No's are: 15100001, 15100002, 15100003........n 
where, 15 is a "year" and 100001 are "running numbers"

[image]

**Requirement is:** I want to show the "InvoiceLineNo" column data as Group wise.

*Example:*

for 1st "Business Unit" group (i.e., SUNWAY LEISURE SDN BHD (CARNIVAL)),
InvoiceLineNo shall be: 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08

for 2nd "Business Unit" group (i.e., SUNWAY MALL PARKING SDN BHD), 
InvoiceLineNo shall be: 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08

Similarly, I want to show the "InvoiceNo" column data as Group wise.

*Example:*

for 1st "Business Unit" group (i.e., SUNWAY LEISURE SDN BHD (CARNIVAL)),
InvoiceNo shall be: 15100001,15100001,15100001,15100001,15100001,15100001,15100001,15100001

for 2nd "Business Unit" group (i.e., SUNWAY MALL PARKING SDN BHD), 
InvoiceNo shall be: 15100002,15100002,15100002,15100002,15100002,15100002,15100002,15100002

"InvoiceNo" column data will always be unique for different "Business Unit".

I want output to be like below snapshot:

[image]

I can autogenerate the numbers serial wise but I am not getting how to autogenerate the 2 column values based on Group and show them like
that.

Please help me to achieve it. Please do reply.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Below is the Stored Procedure I am using to generate autogenerated numbers in RadGrid's 2 column's:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SDM_Assign_RunningNo]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName as nvarchar(50),
    @NewID as nvarchar(50) OUTPUT
    AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


       DECLARE @rn_year as nvarchar(50)

       --Get Year From table            
       SELECT @rn_year =RNYear FROM dbo.SDM_Tran_RunningNo
       WHERE RNYear= YEAR(GetDate())

       --get last 2 digits of year
       Declare @2digit_rn_year as nvarchar(50)

       SELECT @2digit_rn_year = RNYear % 100 FROM dbo.SDM_Tran_RunningNo
       WHERE RNYear= YEAR(GetDate())


        IF @TableName='SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice_No'
    BEGIN   
        SELECT @NewID=Next_InvoiceNo FROM dbo.SDM_Tran_RunningNo
        WHERE RNYear=@rn_year

        UPDATE dbo.SDM_Tran_RunningNo
        SET Next_InvoiceNo=Next_InvoiceNo+1  
        WHERE RNYear=@rn_year

        SET @NewID = @2digit_rn_year +'1'+RIGHT('000000' + CAST(@NewID as varchar(10)), 5)
    END

    ELSE IF @TableName='SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice_LineNo'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @NewID=Next_InvoiceLineNo FROM dbo.SDM_Tran_RunningNo
        WHERE RNYear=@rn_year

        UPDATE dbo.SDM_Tran_RunningNo
        SET Next_InvoiceLineNo=Next_InvoiceLineNo+1  
        WHERE RNYear=@rn_year

        SET @NewID = RIGHT('000000' + CAST(@NewID as varchar(10)), 2)
    END

END
```

And then inserting the 2 column values into Table as below (using Stored Procedure),
to display it in RadGrid:

```
    DECLARE @InvoiceNo as nvarchar(50)
--SP to generate new Invoice No 
EXEC dbo.SDM_Assign_RunningNo
@TableName='SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice_No',
@NewID = @InvoiceNo OUTPUT

DECLARE @InvoiceLineNo as nvarchar(50)
--SP to generate new Invoice Line No 
EXEC dbo.SDM_Assign_RunningNo
@TableName='SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice_LineNo',
@NewID = @InvoiceLineNo OUTPUT

INSERT INTO SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice
VALUES (@InvoiceID,
@SPfoID, 
@InvoiceLineNo, @InvoiceNo, @InvoiceType, 
@BillingIDfoID, @BusinessUnit, @DirectCost,
@Status, GETDATE(), @AccountCode)
```

Comment: I think you should post this to SQL session but not .Net/RadGrid.... I believe this is SQL question...

Comment: @nicholas: Thank you for the reply. Did the changes. Please let me know some solution for this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you for the reply. I am using "Sql Server" database.

Comment: Please post your SQL query so we can help you to identify..

Comment: @nicholas: Please see the Edit section in my posted question. I had added the `Stored Procedure` that I am using to get autogenerated numbers in specific format defined in my posted question. Please help me.

Comment: @nicholas: Please suggest some solution based on my requirement? Please reply

Comment: My SQL skill not good.... Anyway I'm still figuring out...

Comment: @nicholas: Thank you for the reply. If any confusion u may ask me. you may refer to the snapshots for proper understanding of my scenario. I have cropped the previous snapshot with only my requirement.

Comment: Why don't you try to achieve it in a Front-end(ASPX)?

Comment: Did you try sortExpressions?

Comment: @SankarRaj: I am just following the standard of my Project in which requirement is to use Stored Procedure. I did not tried SortExpression. But still I would like to know the solution of my requirement from code behind. 
Thank you

Comment: ok. Let it be... Then. Can you point-out the query which is passing the datasource to the Radgrid.

Comment: Do you want solution from Sp or C#

Comment: I think SP will be better. This is my query to bind data in RadGrid `SELECT * From [SDM_DB].[dbo].[SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice]
 where SPfoID=@SPfoID` data coming in this table is from the `[SDM_Insert_Invoice_Test]` Stored Procedure, that I had posted in my 2nd reply (Ignore Update query in that, its solution to my requirement suggested by @nicholas)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89898/discussion-between-user3196511-and-sankar-raj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a concept... you might need to modify it to suit your requirement.

```
    DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( 
InvoiceID nvarchar(50), 
SPfoID nvarchar(50), 
InvoiceLineNo nvarchar(50), 
InvoiceNo nvarchar(50), 
InvoiceType nvarchar(50), 
BillingIDfoID nvarchar(50), 
BusinessUnit nvarchar(2000),
DirectCost nvarchar(2000),
Status nvarchar(10),
Date datetime,
AccountCode nvarchar(1000)
) 

DECLARE @Temp1 TABLE ( 
OrderID INT IDENTITY, -- Added This so It Will follow this new Identity Row 
InvoiceID nvarchar(50), 
SPfoID nvarchar(50), 
InvoiceLineNo nvarchar(50), 
InvoiceNo nvarchar(50), 
InvoiceType nvarchar(50), 
BillingIDfoID nvarchar(50), 
BusinessUnit nvarchar(2000),
DirectCost nvarchar(2000),
Status nvarchar(10),
Date datetime,
AccountCode nvarchar(1000)
) 

DECLARE @CompanyValue nvarchar(2000) = '' --BusinessUnit datatype
DECLARE @Counter nvarchar(50) = '0' --InvoiceNo datatype
DECLARE @InvoiceLine INT = 1 
DECLARE @Year INT = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
DECLARE @ShortYear VARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @Year), 3, 2) 

EXEC dbo._RunningNo
    @TableName='Invoice',
    @NewID = InvoiceID --OUTPUT

INSERT INTO @Temp (InvoiceID, SPfoID, InvoiceType, BillingIDfoID, BusinessUnit, DirectCost, Status, Date, AccountCode)
SELECT InvoiceID, SPfoID, InvoiceType, BillingIDfoID, BusinessUnit, DirectCost, Status, Date, AccountCode FROM [MainTable] ORDER BY BusinessUnit

INSERT INTO @Temp1 
SELECT * FROM @Temp ORDER BY BusinessUnit 

SELECT * FROM @Temp 
SELECT * FROM @Temp1 -- before update

--Update @Temp1 table
UPDATE @Temp1 
SET 
@Counter = InvoiceNo = CASE WHEN @CompanyValue = '' OR @CompanyValue = BusinessUnit THEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CONVERT(INT,@Counter) + 1)) ELSE '1' END, 
@InvoiceLine = CASE WHEN @CompanyValue = '' OR @CompanyValue = BusinessUnit THEN @InvoiceLine ELSE @InvoiceLine + 1 END, 
@CompanyValue = BusinessUnit, 
InvoiceLineNo = @ShortYear + '10000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), @InvoiceLine) 

SELECT * FROM @Temp1 --after update

--Update main table
UPDATE g
SET  g.InvoiceLineNo = t.InvoiceLineNo,
     g.InvoiceNo = t.InvoiceNo
FROM  SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice g
INNER JOIN @Temp1 t 
ON g.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID


Select * from [MainTable]
ORDER BY BusinessUnit;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. When I modify your solution as per my requirement, I get this error: `Data type int of receiving variable is not equal to the data type nvarchar of column 'InvoiceNo'.` Please note that `DataTypes` of all columns in my Table are `nvarchar(50)` except Primary key ([bigint]) and Date ([datetime]) column. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: Please check my reply.

Comment: Thank you nicholas. Your solution is working as per my requirement.